# Is there an easy way to hide multiple elements made out of arrays

Tags: angular

I'm trying to hide an element in a most efficient way, but I do not know how. I like to do it in a Jquery way where I give each element an attribute of ID and do it like this, `$("div" + id).hide();`. Is there a way to do it in angular?

**I do it like this.**

> **HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let arr of arrs; let i = index">
   <div #div1> {{arr.name}} </div>
   <div>
        <button (click)="hideSomeElement(div1, div2, div3)">
   </div>
   <div #div2> {{arr.name}} </div>
   <div #div3> {{arr.name}} </div>
</div>
```

> **My .ts**

```
let arrs = [
    {
      id: 0,
      name: 'arr1'
    }, {
      id: 1,
      name: 'arr2'
    }
];

hideSomeElement(d1, d2, d3) {
   d1.hidden = true;
   d2.hidden = true;
   d3.hidden = true;
}
```

Comment: you can use *ngIf to hide elements.

Comment: if you want to hide it then filter the array

Answer (score 1):

A better way to go about doing that would be to add a new property to each item in the `arrs`. Something like `visibility`. Set it to `false` based on `id`s passed by the function call:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  arrs = [
    {
      id: 0,
      name: 'arr1',
      visible: true,
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'arr2',
      visible: true,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'arr3',
      visible: true,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'arr4',
      visible: true,
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'arr5',
      visible: true,
    },
  ];

  hideSomeElement(...divIdsToHide) {
    this.arrs.forEach(arr => {
      arr.visible = divIdsToHide.indexOf(arr.id) > -1 ? false : true;
    });
  }
}
```

And in your Template:

```
<div *ngFor="let arr of arrs; let i = index">
  <span *ngIf="arr.visible">
    {{arr.name}}
  </span>
</div>
<button 
  (click)="hideSomeElement(1, 2, 3)">
  Hide Divs
</button>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pyukpm?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.

Answer (score 0):

To access elements from template, you can use **[ViewChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren)**

Your template would get modified like this

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of arrs">
  <div #myDivs style="border:solid 1px black; margin:10px 0 10px 0; width:100px; height:100px;">
    {{item.name}}
  </div>
</div>
<button (click)="hideSomeElement(0,2)">Hide Element</button>
```

and your component would be like this

```js
import { Component, ViewChildren, QueryList, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  @ViewChildren("myDivs") myDivs: QueryList<ElementRef>;


  public arrs = [
    {
      id: 0,
      name: 'arr1'
    }, {
      id: 1,
      name: 'arr2'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'arr3'
    }
];
public hideSomeElement(...elemIndex){
this.myDivs.forEach((elem,index)=>{
  if(elemIndex.indexOf(index))
  {
    elem.nativeElement.style.display="none";
  }
});
}
}
```

> Here is a [**working stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e6bniq).